# Is Visual Studio taking dlls from GAC while building?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, gac

I am using Visual Studio and Windows environment.

The situation is like this:

On the first environment "A" I am building the application.
In bin directory of that project I have my own dll.
Same dll, but different version (old version with an error in code) I have in GAC of this environment.
So running this application on that environment would produce an error because my application would use this dll from GAC, so old dll, bugged version.

The question is what would be if I build this application on the first environment "A" (with wrong dll in GAC) and test this application on the second environment "B" where there is no dll in GAC.

Would Visual Studio take dll from GAC or from dll while building the project ?

If the question is not clear please ask the question.

Regards

Comment: What about [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies) isn't clear?

Comment: The notion of a *reference assembly* is quite holy in .NET.  It must be an assembly that declares the public types that you use in your program, only the type declarations are used.  It never, never comes from the GAC.   The framework assemblies are a good example, they live in the c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies directory.  Allowing you to target a framework version that you don't actually have installed on your machine.  The GAC is a deployment detail, useful to have different versions of a library on the user's machine without breaking old programs that were not recompiled.

Comment: So as long as you don't force the compiler to retrieve the reference assembly from a GAC directory, made intentionally difficult in .NET v2 but easier in .NET v4, you can't create the mishap that you describe.